# Add multiplayer support to a single player game

Tags: python

I've created a single player cricket game all using logic bricks. But now I would like to make that multiplayer game so that multiple people can play on their respective machines. Is there any way to integrate networking using logic bricks, if not, how to do it via python?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no simple step by step answer to this question, since as far as I know, BGE doesn't have integrated multiplayer elements. This means you need to write the multiplayer logic yourself in a way that is very specific to your game. Not impossible, but you should probably learn about communication protocols and libraries in python and think how you want to implement this.

Comment: Hi, I know how to create a  basic client/server architecture in python. Mainly I would like to ask, how to send the game data from a client to server and vice-versa. Should I convert the game created using logic bricks to an equivalent python code or is there any way to send a complete game data via python without converting it to any python code?